# Invalid use of template-name 'SmartArray' without an argument list

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

So the title states the problem I'm running into with my class constructors/destructor. Here's my code:

```
    template <class ArrType>
    class SmartArray{
        public:
        ArrType *elements;              // pointer that will point to dynamic array
        int length();                   // function to return array length
        SmartArray<ArrType>();          // default constructor
        SmartArray(int arrSize);        // constructor that initializes array size
        ~SmartArray();                  // destructor
        void resizeArr(int newsize);        // function that resizes array
        SmartArray(const SmartArray& otherObject);  // copy constructor
```

And here's the default constructor:

```
    SmartArray::SmartArray(){
        arrSize = 0;
        elements = new ArrType[arrSize];
        cout << "Created array using default constructor." << endl;     // letting user know that object was successfully created
    }
```

I did try looking the problem up but either those programs were too advanced for me to understand or I was just too stupid. In any case, I'm hoping there's a simple fix for this.

Comment: `SmartArray<ArrType>();` should just be `SmartArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `template` keyword to define the constructor, also:

```
template<class ArrayType>
SmartArray<ArrayType>::SmartArray(){

   // ...
```

P.S. if you can confirm that you have this constructor definition placed in a separate `.cpp` file, your question will, unfortunately, also have to be closed as [a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).